# In java,how to check elements in a 1-D array are different to each other?

Tags: java, arrays

For example,I have an 1-D array ,how can I check if all the elements are different?(no one same with other,all of them should be different) Use for-loop?Or something else?

I thought maybe this,but cannot be true:

```
int []array={1,2,3,4,4,6}

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  if(a[i]!=a[i+1])
    return true;
  else 
    return false;
```

}

so is there some good method can use to check different?

Comment: If the array is assummed to be sorted, that's ok. But make the counter stop at `a.length - 1`

Comment: All of the answers below are variations on the same idea:  You must somehow compare every member of the array to every other member of the array.  The Set-based answers do it behind-the-scenes, while Robin Krahl's answer does it explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

Add all items from the array into a Set and check the set size with the original array size.

If they're different sizes, then there's a duplicate element.

Comment: There is faster than that; try and `.add()` to the set element by element; if it returns `false` at one point, there is at least one duplicate, therefore all elements are not unique

Answer (score 2):

Create a `HashSet` (or another kind of `Set`), and loop through the elements of your array.  Add them one at a time.  If the element already exists in the `Set`, then not all are different and you can return `false`.  You can tell this if [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) returns `false`; then you *don't* have to check the rest of the array.  If you finish with the entire array and none are the same, then they're all different and you can return `true`.

The problem with your current code is that you only check the first and second elements, and you return something right away based on that comparison, and you don't consider the rest of the elements.

Comment: Uh no. You cannot use a `TreeSet` for instance. Not unless the elements implement `Comparable`. Nor can you use an `IdentityHashSet`. In fact, only `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` fit the bill.

Comment: @fge Good point about not all implementations of `Set` are able to be used here.  However, in this case, with `Integer`s, a `TreeSet` can be used, because `Integer` is `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  For example, you can use two `for` loops:

```
boolean hasDuplicates(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If that’s too much writing for you, you can just create a `Set` from the array and compare the size of the set and the array.  The set automatically drops duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> values = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
assertEquals(array.length, values.size());
```